# Ubuntu installed from mini-ISO under VirtualBox doesn't boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I installed the mini ISO of Ubuntu 11.04 in VirtualBox. After unmounting the ISO image and booting, I can see only black screen for about two hours? Is it normal? What can I do with it in virtual box and proceed with running the system successfully?

thank you

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9966/with-quiet-kernel-option-in-my-grub-entry-can-i-make-the-boot-messages-visible/9982#9982) to debug your problem. When you start the virtual machine and the bootloader loads, press `Shift`, then `e` to modify the options, remove `quiet` and `splash` (or add `nosplash` at the end).

Comment: I tried it, it stuck after `virtual machine additions` so I installed it but after installation `Shift` does not work to make it more verbose. I'm looking at logs but I don't understand where could be the fault.

Comment: You mean you installed *VirtualBox Guest Additions* using an iso image? You probably need to remove it from the configuration of the machine now - it may be trying to boot from that image instead of Ubuntu. What logs are you writing about? What do they contain? Don't you think they can be helpful?

Comment: Yes, I installed `VirtualBox Guest Additions` using `apt-get`. Which configuration do you mean? [Here](http://www.2shared.com/file/-wcmqW8d/11_04_mini-2011-10-12-13-39-13.html) is one of the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VirtualBox log that you posted indicates that your installation (the guest Ubuntu system on virtual disk) is broken - notice all the `BIOS: Boot`-like messages - the machine tries to boot, but fails over and over again. The system probably does not boot at all or fails early - it is hard to tell just from the VirtualBox logs. If possible, try to reinstall this virtual system.

Comment: I already tried it but had problems with reinstalling. I downloaded deb packages and reinstallation didn't help. I installed the old packages again. But now I have stuck and can't remove nor install with `apt`. If you're good at installing, I can send you output of everything to pastebin.

Comment: Hold on - what you mean with "downloaded deb packages" or using `apt`? What are/were you reinstalling? VirtualBox? You should re-install **the virtual Ubuntu machine**, not the VirtualBox application.

Comment: Yes, OK, I will try to reinstall it, but it takes (I guess) about two hours.

Comment: Yes, something about that. Otherwise, you might create a new virtual machine with a separate virtual disk. And make sure, while setting it up, to choose appropriate settings (like system type: Ubuntu).

Comment: I reinstalled the virtual machine. After reboot I have chosen boot device with F12, I press 1 because I want to boot from harddrive, nothing happens, when I hold shift, the menu (where I can delete quiet and splash) won't appear

Comment: Maybe this problem is related to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31032/unable-to-boot-the-operating-system) problem. I can't reconstruct the same environment, so I will close the question.